# convert one field to multiple values for solr data import handler

Tags: templates, solr, dih

I want to build index from mysql table via DIH. One column is an integer type called "tags", which is used as a bitwise process query in mysql.

```
    select * from mytable where (tags & 1) > 0
```

So, I intend to convert the "tags" into multiple values in data import handler, so that I can use BooleanQuery for better performance.

One solution might create a customized DIH template, could you please give me some advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I got your use case, However you can use the tags field and Use [ScriptTransformer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#ScriptTransformer) to convert it into multivalued fields

Example -

Data Config - Add custom field -

```
<script><![CDATA[
        function addfield(row){
            var fieldName = row.get('tags');
            // Remove tags and Split/Convert tags as Array for Multivalued field
            row.put(fieldName, tagsarray);
            return row;
        }
]]></script>
```